# How to rename a file using NSFileManager

Tags: nsfilemanager

I have a single file named **a.caf** in the documents directory. I would like to rename it when user types into a `UITextField` and presses change (the text entered in the `UITextField` should be the new filename).

How can I do this?

Comment: This question will answer yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873522/rename-file-in-cocoa

Answer (score 85):

You can use [moveItemAtPath](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:).

```c
NSError * err = NULL;
NSFileManager * fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
BOOL result = [fm moveItemAtPath:@"/tmp/test.tt" toPath:@"/tmp/dstpath.tt" error:&err];
if(!result)
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", err);
[fm release];
```

Comment: This is moving file from one folder to another, anyways it's working but when there is space in the filename it's not working. ex: **Path:: /tmp/test file.tt toPath: /tmp/dst path.tt** it's an url space is automatically converting to %20. Is there any other possibulity renaming folder without URL/moving.??

Answer (score 15):

To keep this question *up-to-date*, I'm adding the **Swift** version as well:

```swift
let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
let originPath = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("/tmp/a.caf")
let destinationPath = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("/tmp/xyz.caf")

var moveError: NSError?
if !manager.moveItemAtPath(originPath, toPath: destinationPath, error: &moveError) {
    println(moveError!.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: I haven't kept it up-to-date. Thanks for the heads up, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 9):

This is the function by daehan park to converted to Swift 3 and works with Swift 4 & 5:

```swift
func moveFile(pre: String, move: String) -> Bool {
    do {
        try FileManager.default.moveItem(atPath: pre, toPath: move)
        return true
    } catch {
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Worked on **Swift 2.2**

```swift
func moveFile(pre: String, move: String) -> Bool {
    do {
        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().moveItemAtPath(pre, toPath: move)
        return true
    } catch {
        return false
    }
}
```