# How to rename files from Documents directory?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am saving my files in Document directory named `1.png`, `2.png`, `3.png`, `4.png`, `5.png`. If I delete the original file `3.png`, how do I rename files `4.png` and `5.png` to be called `3.png` and `4.png` respectively?

This is the code I am using to write the files in the first place:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
[appDel.photo addObject:@"photo"];
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.png", [appDel.photo count]];
appDel.numberPhoto = [appDel.photo count];
NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                  imageName];
NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image); 
[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Have you tried to write any code that would do this for you ?

Comment: This is the point. I do not know how to get the file and renaming it ((( and I do not know how to write this code

Comment: If you are saving the files through code to your directory then through the same method you can rename them. Just over write the name of the file in the method.

Comment: How do you save the files? Plist, SQL, what is the method of saving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get `NSDocuments` directory use :

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFile.txt"];
```

How to rename file you can find here:

[How to rename a file using NSFileManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500469/how-to-rename-file-using-nsfilemanager)

If you do not know the names of the files in documents directory you can use :

```
NSArray *directoryContent = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
```

This array contains all filenames you need. So you can rename them all.

Comment: Yes, i know my files names. Thanks, i will try this advise about renaming