# How to rename files/folders from document folder programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-rename

I am working on functionality to save video files in document folder of application in iOS.

How to **rename some files programmatically**?

Comment: check this url  http://iosdevelopertips.com/data-file-management/iphone-file-system-creating-renaming-and-deleting-files.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try this code :

```
NSError * err = NULL;
NSFileManager * fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
BOOL result = [fm moveItemAtPath:@"/tmp/test.tt" toPath:@"/tmp/dstpath.tt" error:&err];
if(!result)
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", err);
```

other wise use this method to rename file

```
- (void)renameFileWithName:(NSString *)srcName toName:(NSString *)dstName
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePathSrc = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:srcName];
    NSString *filePathDst = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:dstName];
    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([manager fileExistsAtPath:filePathSrc]) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        [manager moveItemAtPath:filePathSrc toPath:filePathDst error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"There is an Error: %@", error);
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"File %@ doesn't exists", srcName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no Direct API to rename the file . Though when you move the file from one place to another place, if that file in destination path not exists then iOS will create the file in the given name. For file you can just give the New name of your file, how it should be displayed/referenced.

[you could check this answer. Good luck!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3501364/675170)